# ChangeCollection type into Appointment type EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am doing syncing using Exchange server web services(EWS). TO do sync need to identify  change items in Calendar after last sync. To do that [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693003%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) help you a lot.
While using that i need to take appointment start,end etc...

```
ChangeCollection<ItemChange> allExchEvents = service.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar), PropertySet.FirstClassProperties, null, 512, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, sSyncState);
```

How could i convert this change events to Appointment type ?

Answer (score -1):

After looking at MSDN document and some blogs I found the answer.

```
 ChangeCollection<ItemChange> icc = service.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar), PropertySet.FirstClassProperties, null, 512, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, sSyncState);
 sSyncState = icc.SyncState;

 if (icc.Count == 0)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("There are no item changes to synchronize.");
 }
 else
 {        
   foreach (ItemChange ic in icc)
   {
     **Appointment ap = (Appointment)ic.Item;**
   }
 }
```

Use "ap" object to retrieve appointment inner properties.